# How to add check in embed definitions?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi there I'm trying to add checks to my embed definitions that return the users information from the sql database.

What I'd like to achieve is to check if the user has set a gametag and then if the data isn't there then don't show it on their profile.

However, I'm was able to pass a check to see if the user data is in the database if the result is None it will turn *Steam None* where as I rather not show it altogether.

Here is what I'm working with:

````py
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    async def profile(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
        user = user or ctx.author
        db = sqlite3.connect('profiles.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT profile FROM profile WHERE username={user.id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT steam FROM profile WHERE username={user.id}")
        result2 = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            await ctx.send(f"{user.display_name}'s bio has not been created yet.")
        elif result4:
            steam = f"**Steam** [{result2[0]}](http://steam.com/{result2[0]})" #return data from database.
        else:
            steam = "" # return nothing if nothing returned from database.    
        desc = f"{(result[0])} \n\n {steam}:" # define a embed description as f-string 
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name}'s Profile", description=desc, color=user.colour)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you do not want `result2[0]` to be `None`, whereas you are checking for `result` to be `None`. Make sure to check for both `result2` and `result2[0]` to be not `None` and that should fix it.

Also, if that is supposed to stop the embed creation, you might want to `return` after the `await ctx.send(...)` (under "`if result == None:`").

Comment: Thanks that seems to work but I would also like to try and remove the `**Steam**` some how

Comment: @James I don't get you: in that case, you can simply remove `**Steam**` from the string, no?